# What is special with replace() method in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

First of all I'm a beginner in Python. Therefore I'm sorry if my question seems ridiculous for you. If you have a string value, for example:

```
a = 'Hello 11'
```

if you type:

```
a[-1] = str(int(a[-1]) + 1)
```

the result will be: `'2'`

but if you type:

```
a.replace(a[-1], str(int(a[-1]) + 1))
```

the result will be:

'`Hello 22'` instead of `'Hello 12'`

Why that happens?

Comment: `a[-1] = str(int(a[-1]) + 1)` will get the following error:                               `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the parts:

```
>>> a[-1]
'1'
>>> str(int(a[-1]) + 1)
'2'
```

This means:

```
>>> a.replace(a[-1], str(int(a[-1]) + 1))
```

does this:

```
>>> a.replace('1', '2')
'Hello 22'
```

It replaces the string `1` by the string `2`.

In Python strings are immutable. Therefore, this:

```
>>> a[-1] = str(int(a[-1]) + 1)
```

does not work:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 1):

replace performs a match operation and the value of `a[-1]`, i.e. 1, is matched 2 times in the string

if you want to replace only the last character:

```
a = a[:-1] + str(int(a[-1]) + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)